# Is it possible to intercept rebol's console error?

Tags: rebol

Let's say I type a stupid command in Rebol Console like

```
>> AWordThatMeansNothing
** Script Error: AWordThatMeansNothing has no value
** Near: AWordThatMeansNothing
>>
```

I want to intercept the above error to display another message or do anything I need to when I get an error in Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a small front end to the console. Not perfect, but a start:

```
forever [
    if error? try [
        print do input][
           print "went bad!"
           ]
   ]
```

Comment: Isn't Rebol 3 allows to Hook Error and if possible any event like in Windows System where you can intercept anything ?

Comment: But will try your solution as I'm still on Rebol 2 :)